# Inherit parent factory method

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have class A and its child class B which inherits from A.

Now, I have a class method in A which takes the instance from somewhere with "inout" and checks if it is nil, if not it fills it with necessary parameters. For example:

```
class A
{
    class func fillInstance(inout instance : Self, parameters : [String]) -> Self
    {
          guard let instance = instance else
         {
             return Self(parameters : parameters)
         }

         return instance
    }
}
```

Now, of course nothing which has Self there is not valid :)

I need a way to make it valid. Is it possible in Swift?

Everything here is fiction. I just need to be able to implement the idea of a class method which can be inherited by a child and which would allow instantiating an instance according to the class that called that class method. I don't want to check for the type because it can be inherited down the child hierarchy a lot of times (I mean it can become A -> B -> C -> D -> E.... and all inherit one from another). Please help :)

Comment: There is no necessity to make the parameter `inout`, classes are always passed by reference

Comment: I tested it. If I assign a value to the instance inside my function, that value will not be reflected in the scope in which that instance was passed as a parameter. As I understand it's more of a local copy, thus this why inout exist -> To explicitly show that you want to modify the original reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the chain assignment would not carry the class type used as parameter.  But you can fix that using generics:

```
 class A
 {
    class func fillInstance<T:A>(instance : T, parameters : [String]) -> T
    { 
       // do your stuff here
       instance.filledContent["A.fillInstance"] = "\(parameters)"
       return instance 
    }

    class func fillInstance<T:A>(instance : T?, parameters : [String]) -> T?
    {
       if instance != nil 
       { 
         let existing:T = T.fillInstance(instance!, parameters:parameters)
         return existing
       }
       return nil
    } 

    var filledContent:[String:String] = [:]
 }

 class B:A
 {
    func showContent() -> String { return "Showing: \(filledContent)" }

    override class func fillInstance<T:A>(instance : T, parameters : [String]) -> T
    { 
      instance.filledContent["B.fillInstance"] = "B Specific Filling"
      return A.fillInstance(instance, parameters:parameters) 
    }
 }

 let anInstanceOfA = A()

 A.fillInstance(anInstanceOfA, parameters: ["A->Param","To A"]).filledContent
 // ["A.fillInstance": "["A->Param", "To A"]"]

 let anInstanceOfB = B()

 A.fillInstance(anInstanceOfB, parameters: ["A->Param","To B"]).showContent()
 // "Showing: ["A.fillInstance": "["A->Param", "To B"]"]"

 var optionalA:A? = A()

 A.fillInstance(optionalA, parameters: ["A->Param","To A?"])?.filledContent
 // ["A.fillInstance": "["A->Param", "To A?"]"]
 B.fillInstance(optionalA, parameters: ["B->Param","To A?"])?.filledContent
 // ["A.fillInstance": "["B->Param", "To A?"]"]
 optionalA = nil
 A.fillInstance(optionalA, parameters: ["A->Param","To A?(nil)"])?.filledContent
 // nil

 var optionalB:B? = B()
 A.fillInstance(optionalB, parameters: ["A->Param","To B?"])?.showContent()
 // "Showing: ["B.fillInstance": "B Specific Filling", "A.fillInstance": "["A->Param", "To B?"]"]"
 B.fillInstance(optionalB, parameters: ["B->Param","To B?"])?.showContent()
 // "Showing: ["B.fillInstance": "B Specific Filling", "A.fillInstance": "["B->Param", "To B?"]"]"
 optionalB = nil
 A.fillInstance(optionalB, parameters: ["A->Param","To B?(nil)"])?.showContent()
 // nil
 B.fillInstance(optionalB, parameters: ["B->Param","To B?(nil)"])?.showContent()
 // nil
```

Notice that no matter which class function you use, the compiler always executes the class function corresponding to the class of the instance given as parameter.
I'm not sure that's what you want, bu then again, I couldn't imagine a scenario where you would want to fill an instance of B with only the part of the logic that applies to A (and not do the extra in the B override).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for you, but you could do something like this:

```
class A {
    var parameters: [String]!

    class func fillInstance(instance: A?, parameters : [String]) -> A? {
        if instance == nil {
            return self.init(parameters: parameters)
        }
        instance!.setParameters(parameters)
        return instance
    }

    func setParameters(parameters: [String]) {
        self.parameters = parameters
    }

    required init(parameters: [String]) {
        self.parameters = parameters
    }
}
```

You can send an instance of a subclass of `A` to `fillInstance`:

```
class B: A {}

let b1 = A.fillInstance(B(), parameters: ["exists"]) as! B
```

Or you can send nil from a subclass of `A` and construct an objet of that subclass:

```
let b2 = B.fillInstance(nil, parameters: ["from nil"]) as! B
```

But there is probably better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thx for trying. Unfortunately my aim was to be able to modify the instance I'm passing by and specifically to treat the case where it is an optional which has a nil value. But whatever I do with my instance inside my class A func, that is not reflected to the instance in the bigger scope where this func was called. Also I'm not sure that forcing to B actually makes it a B class instance. I think if you would call a B instance specific func on it, you would get an error. But I should check.

Comment: About the last issue, yes you get a B instance, there is no error

Answer (score 0):

That all seems unwieldy to me.  Unless your code intends to change to swap the object instance in the variable being passed, there is no need to use inout at all.  If this were a Struct, then perhaps there might be a need for it.

You can let the compiler solve this for you:

```
class A
{
   class func fillInstance(instance : A, parameters : [String]) -> A
   { 
      // do your stuff here
      return instance 
   }

   class func fillInstance(instance : A?, parameters : [String]) -> A?
   {
      if instance != nil 
      { 
        let existing:A = fillInstance(instance!, parameters:parameters)
        return existing
      }
      return nil
   }     
}
```

Note: this could be even simpler if you were not returning the instance.  you shouldn't need to given that the object has been modified.  Or is that just for convenience in making chained assignments ?

Comment: chained assignments. But this will not work well after inheritance because the method states it will be returning A type instance. And I would need it to be able in case of B class to return B instance.. in case of C class C instance and that this would happen only by inheriting from A. Let me know if I understood wrong.